# Can I talk while playing music?

Tags: music, playback, voice, internet-radio, shoutcast

I have taken the advice of some people on here to use Shoutcast for my online radio station, but I have run into a problem. I need to be able to talk while the music is playing. Not through the entire song of course, just to tell what the song is and stuff like that. I know this is possible, a little Googling told me that but what I wasn't able to find is how to do that!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.  The easiest way is to use an external mixer.  This way you can control the levels appropriately.  On the cheap end, you can find some 4 or 6 channel [mixers for not much more than $50](http://www.americanmusical.com/Item--i-BEH-XENTX802-LIST).  Head to your nearest used music shop and you may find some for cheaper.  Basically, you will hook up the audio output from your computer up one of the inputs on the mixer, and hook your microphones up to the input on the mixer as well.  Then hook the output of the mixer up to the line-in on your sound card.

Another option is to use a [mixer with a USB audio interface built right in](http://www.americanmusical.com/ItemList.aspx?m=556).  You will get better audio quality this way.  With that, you can playback and record right over the same interface, and the only thing you need to hook up to your computer is USB.

Now, if you already have a microphone wired up to the same sound card you are playing out of on your computer, then you can do this without an external mixer.  It is just more of a hassle.  Just set the SHOUTcast DSP to record from the sound card rather than "Winamp".  Then open up the record mixer for your sound card and make sure "Stereo Mix" is checked, along with your microphone.  Again though, this is much more of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but how to do that depends on your client software!

The last time I checked, (using the default winamp plugin shoutcast client) you had to have a microphone plugged in with jack plugs, **not** USB, and you could just select your soundcard as an input source, which would include microphone input, too.

Comment: This is wrong, it has nothing to do with how your microphone is connected.  It only has to do with the microphone being connected to the same sound card that is used for playback.  This could be internal, USB, or otherwise.  Makes no difference.